# Get row by certain value in R

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate

So I have this data table, and I'd like to sort it out by profession (column 'Profissao').
The idea is to make an average of the answers to each column by area of working.

For example:
I need to select every 'Aspeto-A' cell in a row referent to 'Media' job and make the average of all Media people who answered the form.

data table screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah found a solution to the problem, not that difficult, just needed the function aggregate(). Thanks likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture of your data is not as useful as using `dput()`. Since I can't use your data, I'll use the `iris` data set that is included with R:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
aggregate(.~Species, iris, mean)
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
# 2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
# 3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot!
I left an answer to myself explaining what I did.
Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

**It wasn't that hard after all. Probably there is a better way to do it, but this one is working out.**

*AspetoA_Selectiom<-data.frame(Profissao=Profissao,aspetoA=aspetoA)*

*ApetoA_sum <- aggregate(AspetoA_Selectiom$aspetoA, by=list(AspetoA_Selectiom$Profissao), FUN=sum)*

*AspetoA_length <- aggregate(AspetoA_Selectiom$aspetoA, by=list(AspetoA_Selectiom$Profissao), FUN=length)*

*AspetoA_AVG<- ApetoA_sum$x / AspetoA_length$x*